# BIND DNS - Virtualmin on new VPS

Tags: dns, firewall, vps, webmin, virtualmin

Sorry if this question is a duplicate but I'm very confused and tried finding solutions online and testing for a few weeks already.
This question deserve a thread because it's a VPS server by a new provider, and they don't have a KB on it.

I bought a VPS server from let's say ABC provider.
the server is at server.domain1.com with IP1
the domain1 is at godaddy

On Godaddy, I have added 3 hostnames
server.domain1.com
ns1.domain1.com
ns2.domain1.com

all pointing to IP1

then I changed the domain1 nameservers to 
server.domain1.com
ns1.domain1.com
ns2.domain1.com

Then on virtualmin, I have added a master zone with the following setting
A record : 
domain1.com
server.domain1.com
ns1.domain1.com
ns2.domain1.com

NS record : 
server.domain1.com
ns1.domain1.com
ns2.domain1.com

Name alias record :
www.domain1.com

I'm aware that if on Digital Ocean, I would need to point domain to their nameserver, but I have consulted my VPS provider, they said to point to VPS IP. Thats all, nothing more.
But the problem is when I visits the domain, it showed DNS not resolved. What have I done wrong? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Update : It's a conflict of firewall. Deactivate the firewalld and iptables and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow port 80/443 in your firewalld configuration instead of completely disabling it.

[Image of Firewalld configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tery8.png)